# How to capture leftmouse up event by python?

Tags: python, scripting, operator

After seeing `bpy.types.Event` https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Event.html, and some code examples, I cannot find the event of `leftmouse up`, only `LEFTMOUSE` is available. (correct me if it is wrong)

I want to ask how to capture the `leftmouse up` event using python. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned [in the document](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Event.html), the **Event.type** will tell you which key or mouse button sent the event and the **Event.value** specifies if pressing or releasing happened.

So you can do something like below in the modal method of an operator for example:

Here *ctx* is the current context in Blender and the **evt** is **bpy.types.Event** instance

```
def modal(self, ctx, evt):
    if evt.type == 'LEFTMOUSE':
        if evt.value == 'PRESS':
            print('LMB Pressed')
        elif evt.value == 'RELEASE':
            print('LMB Released')
    return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
```

A thorough example of using modal event handler is at the link below.

https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/scripts/templates_py/operator_modal.py